# Unable to mount FreeNAS 9.3.1 NFS share on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs, freenas

I have FreeNAS 9.3.1 running on a computer with an NFS share. I am unable to mount this share via the mount command:

```
mount -t nfs 192.168.0.104:/mnt/NAS /mnt/test
```

on Ubuntu 15.10 or on the FreeNAS computer itself.

I can however, browse through the File GUI and see the folder (Browse Network, FreeNAS, ...) and can access the files that way, just not with nfs.

FreeNAS
/etc/exports

```
/mnt/NAS -alldirs -mapall=mediactr:wheel freenas AMD6Core DellXPS
```

All the machines above can ping the FreeNAS box

Ubuntu 
/etc/fstab

```
192.168.0.104:/mnt/NAS /mnt/FreeNAS nfs async,auto,dev,exec,rw,nouser,vers=3 0 0
```

Command Line fails as well:

```
mount -v -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 192.168.0.104:/mnt/NAS /mnt/FreeNAS
```

The command line gets a timeout, until I added the nfsvers, which now has the protocol unsupported error.

Trying to just mount on the FreeNAS computer to see if the user can do this, using the Shell GUI option from the web interface:
The command liine attempt on the FreeNAS computer itself, gives and error of:

```
nfsd: RPCPROG_NFS: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused
```

The shell starts with a ~#, but maybe I need the sudo there as well?

From Ubuntu 15.10 (192.168.0.103) to FreeNAS (192.168.0.104)

```
8~$ ping 192.168.0.104
PING 192.168.0.104 (192.168.0.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.104: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.214 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.104: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.257 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.104: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.252 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.104 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.214/0.241/0.257/0.019 ms

~$ sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 192.168.0.104:/mnt/NAS /mnt/test 
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Nov 3 08:17:51 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.0.4'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
```